# can we have the modern experience in SharePoint on-premises 2013?

Tags: 2013, modern-experience, sharepoint-on-prem

can we have the modern experience in SharePoint on-premises 2013? Mainly creating modern pages and also creating hub sites?
Thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

No, these features aren't available in SharePoint Server 2013. In addition, Hub Sites are not available in any on-premises version of SharePoint Server, including Subscription Edition.

You can get bare bones minimum modern experience starting with SharePoint 2016 which is improved in 2019 and further improved in Subscription Edition.

Comment: ok thanks a lot for the valuable info